# Question about alternate subset notation

Tags: notation

I am reading a new text, and I have come across the notation '$\Subset$' as well as '$\subset$'. Am I correct in assuming that '$\Subset$' is an alternative method of specifying an improper subset like the usual '$\subseteq$'?

Comment: What text?  What's it all about?  Context is everything.  And have you consulted the end pages?  Sometimes authors have a rundown of symbols there.

Comment: Thank you, I checked the end pages once and overlooked it the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol has no standard meaning. It is up to each author who uses it to supply a definition and explanation of what *he* uses it to mean, early enough to avoid confusing the reader.

Answer (score 0):

After scanning through the end pages more carefully, I found embarrassingly that I missed the answer the first time I looked! In this context (locally integrable functions under Lebesgue measure), the symbol was used to represent a subset whose closure is compact and is also a subset.